# Ufw, allow in/out on enp0s3 192.168.0.0/16

Tags: network-interface, ip, ufw

is it possible work ufw to allow in and out on a specific interface **AND**  ip range at the same time?

ufw allow in/out from enp0s3 192.168.0.0/16   ?

e.g allowing everything on local network, but only on interface enp0s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of had it already. Try this:

```
ufw allow in on enp0s3 from 192.168.0.0/16
ufw allow out on enp0s3 to 192.168.0.0/16
```